# cut a particular number from the url in linux

Tags: linux, awk

I've a file with the below header generated by certain process

```
Link: <https://rnd.corp.zoom/api/v3/repositories/99/issues?state=all&per_page=100&page=2>; rel="next", <https://rnd.corp.zoom/api/v3/repositories/99/issues?state=all&per_page=100&page=8>; rel="last"
```

I want to cut just the number `8` from `page=8` in the above content. How to go about it? Appreciate any help.

Comment: You have two links, the first ends in `page=2`, the second in `page=8`. Do you want only one of them, or both?

Comment: I want only the `8` in the `page=8` to be printed. Basically I need to fetch the last page from the header that I receive from the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
$ cat  f
Link: <https://rnd.corp.zoom/api/v3/repositories/99/issues?state=all&per_page=100&page=2>; rel="next", <https://rnd.corp.zoom/api/v3/repositories/99/issues?state=all&per_page=100&page=8>; rel="last"

$ awk -F'[&=<>]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~ /^page$/) {print $(i+1)}}' f
2
8
```

If it is getting appended then you will get the last value using below awk :

```
$ awk -F'[&=<>]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if($i ~ /^page$/) {kk=$(i+1)}} END{print kk}' ff
8
```

> Limitation : Currently you have page=2 and page=8 and above command
>   will print the last page value.

And if you always want to print the 2nd value `"8"` (Added extra lines to the existing url, considering that it will keep on increasing and you always need the 2nd value then use below) -

```
$ cat f
Link: <https://rnd.corp.zoom/api/v3/repositories/99/issues?state=all&per_page=100&page=2>; rel="next", <https://rnd.corp.zoom/api/v3/repositories/99/issues?state=all&per_page=100&page=8>; rel="last"
 <https://rnd.corp.zoom/api/v3/repositories/99/issues?state=all&per_page=100&page=8>; rel="last"

$ awk -v k=1 -F'[&=<>]' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(($i ~ /^page$/) && (k==2) ) {print $(i+1)} k++}' f
8
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is an implementation using `grep`:

```
grep -Po "&page=[0-9]*" <file_name> | grep -Po "[0-9]*"
```

Example:

```
echo 'Link: <https://rnd.corp.zoom/api/v3/repositories/99/issues?state=all&per_page=100&page=2>; rel="next", <https://rnd.corp.zoom/api/v3/repositories/99/issues?state=all&per_page=100&page=8000>; rel="last"' | grep -Po "&page=[0-9]*" | grep -Po "[0-9]*"
```

Comment: Thanks @learningloop. This prints both 2 and 8. I want to print only 8. Also, the number will increase in future and become two digit, three digit etc., Is there any solution you could think of ?

Comment: Then adding `| tail -1` will always print last returned page number.

Answer (score 0):

This will produces the result as expected.

```
 echo 'Link: <https://rnd.corp.zoom/api/v3/repositories/99/issues?state=all&per_page=100&page=2>; rel="next", <https://rnd.corp.zoom/api/v3/repositories/99/issues?state=all&per_page=100&page=12345>; rel="last"' | grep -Po "&page=[0-9]*" |grep -Po "[0-9]*"| awk '2 == NR % $ct'
```

Comment: I think it is over use of grep, those things could be done with a single awk too.

Comment: There are multiple ways to solve the problem, You picked one way, I picked one way, Atlast both got the solution. 
I know **grep** will take more time than awk, but still I preferred this solution because of it's regular expression options.

Answer (score 0):

In awk. `rev`erse the text, remove first `[0-9]+=egap`, output and `rev` again:

```
$ rev foo | awk 'sub(/[0-9]+=egap/,"")||1' |rev
```

Output:

```
Link: <https://rnd.corp.zoom/api/v3/repositories/99/issues?state=all&per_page=100&page=2>; rel="next", <https://rnd.corp.zoom/api/v3/repositories/99/issues?state=all&per_page=100&>; rel="last"
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
awk '{gsub(/.*page=/,"page=");sub(/>.*/,"");print}'   Input_file
```

Simply substitute the all line with .*page= to page= which is nothing but will go till last page string(as * is a greedy regex match), so then substitute >.*(means starting from > to till end of line) with NULL, then print the line which will be page=8 or last value of the page. Off course I am considering that your Input_file is same as example shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'[= >]' '{print $12}' file
8
awk -F= '{split($8,a,">");print a[1]}' file
8
awk -F= '$8=="8>; rel"{print substr($8,1,1)}' file
8
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that a *greedy* regex is needed here (only the *last* occurrence of `&page=` should be matched) enables **a simple `sed` solution**:

```
sed -E 's/^.*&page=([0-9]+).*$/\1/' file
```

- `^.*&page=` matches everything up to the *last* occurrence of `&page` on the line.
- `([0-9]+)` matches one or more digits, and - thanks to enclosure in `(...)` stores the match in the 1st (and only) capture group, which the replacement string then reference as `\1`.
- `.*$` matches any remaining character on the line.
- By virtue of the regex having matched the *entire* line, `\1` therefore results in just the captured number as the output.

The above works **with both GNU and BSD/macOS `sed`** and takes advantage of modern *extended* regular expressions (`-E`), but in case you need **a POSIX-compliant solution** (which must use *basic* regular expressions and is therefore more cumbersome):

```
sed 's/^.*&page=\([0-9]\{1,\}\).*$/\1/' file
```

---

With ***GNU* `grep`** (on Linux, as requested), a single-pass `grep -Po` solution is also possible; like the `sed` solution, it relies on greedily matching up to the *last* `&page=`:

```
grep -Po "^.*&page=\K[0-9]+" file
```

- `-P` activates support for [PRCEs (Perl-compatible Regular Expressions)](http://www.pcre.org/original/doc/html/pcre.html).
- `-o` only outputs the matching part of the line.
- `\K` drops everything matched so far, so that what `[0-9]+` matches - one or more digits - is the only output.